# XQuery concat to the same variable

Tags: for-loop, variables, xquery, saxon

Simple code there-

```
let $sV2 :=''
for $i in (1 to 2)
    let $sV1 := 'test1'
    let $sV2 := if (fn:string-length($sV2) != 0) then fn:concat($sV2,'||',$sV1) else ($sV1)
     return
     <test>{$sV2}</test>
```

i get the same output

```
<test>test1</test>
<test>test1</test>
```

whereas i expect

```
<test>test1</test>
<test>test1||test1</test>
```

what am i doing wrong? i tried to debug but why does V2 initialize to null/'' for second iteration.

Note- I have to use **xquery 1.0** do to some product limitations.

How do i get the expected output?

Comment: An XQuery `for` expression is not a procedural loop and you can't "reassign" values to variables. So I think your approach is wrong, you are trying to use a procedural algorithm in XQuery. You have used the Saxon tag but say you are limited to XQuery 1.0 which doesn't make much sense to me as Saxon for many years now supports XQuery 3.1. So consider using `fold-left`, for instance, if you use Saxon.

Comment: And note in particular that you have two variables called sV2 that are quite unrelated to each other. Binding a value to the second variable called sV2 doesn't change the value of the other variable with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was thinking in java mindset and now i understand the fundamental difference between the two. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery is a functional language. As such, it does not allow you to change the value of a variable once it has been assigned.

There are many other ways to reach the same results, though. Your specific query can e.g. be rewritten as follows:

```
for $i in 1 to 2
return <test>{
  string-join(for $n in 1 to $i return 'test1', '||')
}</test>
```